# How to print the name of each dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have just started coding this semester, so if you can use simple methods to help me find my answer I'd appreciate it. Basically, I just want it to print the name of each dictionary and then list it's contents. Oh, and just so you know, I don't actually even like sports this was just a previous homework assignment that I wanted to improve upon. Here's what I've got and yes, I know it doesn't work the way I want it to:

```
football = {
            'favorite player': 'Troy Aikman',
            'team': 'Dallas Cowboys',
            'number': '8',
            'position': 'quarterback'
           }
baseball = {
            'favorite player': 'Jackie Robinson',
            'team': 'Brooklyn Dodgers',
            'number': '42',
            'position': 'second baseman'
           }
hockey = {
          'favorite player': 'Wayne Gretzky',
          'team': 'New York Rangers',
          'number': '99',
          'position': 'center'
         }

sports = [football, baseball, hockey]
my_sports = ['Football', 'Baseball', 'Hockey']
for my_sport in my_sports:
    print(my_sport)
for sport in sports:
    for question, answer in sport.items():
        print(question.title + ": " + answer)
    print("\n")
```

I want it to print:

```
Football
Favorite player: Troy Aikman
Team: Dallas Cowboys
Number: 8
Position: quarterback

Baseball:
Favorite player: Jackie Robinson
Team: Brooklyn Dodgers
Number: 42
Position: second baseman
```

...and so forth. How do I achieve the results I want? The simpler the better and please use Python 3, I know nothing of Python 2.

Comment: So, can I ask why you tried to do `question.title`? That should throw an `AttributeError`? Is that currently the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: It looks like the title is in one list (my_sports), but the data is in another list (sports). They line up item-to-item at the same index by intentional coincidence, so you just need to access them in the same way. Either use "for index in range(len(my_sports)" or look up the python "zip" function. Good luck.

Comment: Dictionaries *don't have names*.  Variables have names, but you lost any connection with the original variable when you built the `sports` list.  You could add the name as an item in each dict, or do `for name, sport in zip(sports, my_sports):` to loop over the two lists in parallel.

Comment: I just added the title thing as I was typing and forgot the parentheses. My bad, I just started coding after all. Before I added the title I wasn't getting an error, I was just getting the wrong output. Also, I don't know what a zip is yet. Don't think I've gotten there yet in the book. But, my question has been answered in a simplistic way that I can understand by Dharmesh. Thanks a bunch, it's really helped me learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_sports = {'Football': football, 'Baseball' : baseball, 'Hockey' : hockey}
for key,value in my_sports.items():
    print(key)

    for question, answer in value.items():
        print(question + ": " + answer)
    print("\n")
```

Comment: @Ginger: The order that the sport dictionaries keys and associated values (named `question` and `answer` in the code) is arbitrary and can even vary between sports. This is a common issue in many of the other answers, too.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

I edit my answer and now the code below works:

```
my_sports = {'Football': football, 'Baseball' : baseball, 'Hockey' : hockey}

for key,value in my_sports.items():
    print(key)

    for question, answer in value.items():
        print(question + ": " + answer)
    print("\n")
```

This is the result:

```
Football
Favorite Player: Troy Aikman
Team: Dallas Cowboys
Number: 8
Position: quarterback


Baseball
Favorite Player: Jackie Robinson
Team: Brooklyn Dodgers
Number: 42
Position: second baseman


Hockey
Favorite Player: Wayne Gretzky
Team: New York Rangers
Number: 99
Position: center
```

Code here: 
https://repl.it/MOBO/3

Comment: This is going to print all the `sport.keys()` items for _every_ sport each iteration of the outer for `loop`. Besides that, the order of the what is printed will be unpredictable because dictionaries don't preserve ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sports = {"football":football, "baseball":baseball, "hockey":hockey}
for a, b in sports.items():
    print(a)
    for c, d in b.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(c, d))
```

Output:

```
football
position: quarterback
favorite player: Troy Aikman
number: 8
team: Dallas Cowboys
baseball
position: second baseman
favorite player: Jackie Robinson
number: 42
team: Brooklyn Dodgers
hockey
position: center
favorite player: Wayne Gretzky
number: 99
team: New York Rangers
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function seems like the easiest way to combine and pair-up elements from the two lists. Here's how to use it:

```
sports = [football, baseball, hockey]
my_sports = ['Football', 'Baseball', 'Hockey']

for my_sport, sport in zip(my_sports, sports):
    print('\n'.join((
        '{}',  # name of sport
        'Favorite player: {favorite player}',
        'Team: {team}',
        'Number: {number}',
        'Position: {position}')).format(my_sport, **sport) + '\n'
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dictionary={
            "Name":"Ali",
             "Roll":1,
             "Name 1":"asad"
             " Roll 1":2,
             }
Print (Dictionary)
```

Comment: `Print`? Do you mean `print`? Please make sure to actually test out code you share here as an answer.